# How to add credential for private nuget feed into Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

So I have an Azure DevOps Pipelines that looks like this:

[image]

So currently, with NuGet 4.6.2, I can add my credentials/PAT using service endpoint. This is working now.

But, I am stuck with NuGet 4.6.2. If I upgrade to the latest NuGet (5.8), then I will get errors during NuGet restore:

```
Unable to find version '<x.y.z>' of package '<my.object.package>'.
  C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\: 
  Package '<my.object.package.x.y.z>' is not found on source 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: 
  Package '<my.object.package.x.y.z>' is not found on source 'https://<private.nuget.url>: Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at '
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).)
```

My guess is that somehow I need to pass in the credential to the private NuGet feed (outside of the organization) differently - but not sure how. Or maybe I am missing something here?

Answer (score 6):

According to the error message, we could to know it is trying to access your private nuget feed and get this 401 (Unauthorized) error. It seems you did not provide certification information in the `nuget.config` file.

You can try to add the certification information in your `nuget.config` as following:

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="keyName" value="privateFeedUrl" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <keyName>
      <add key="Username" value="%USER_VARIABLE%" />      
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%PAT%" />
    </keyName>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

You can refer to this [thread](https://intercom.help/appcenter/en/articles/2216043-restore-private-azuredevops-package-management-feeds-using-pat) for some more details.

Comment: I did - and I got the same error. Secondly, I really do not want to put my credentials in the nuget.config file (which will be in GitHub) - very unsecure. Any other way like using Service Endpoint that works or any other way? Is there anybody still using private/outside organization feed anymore?

Comment: You can try to reverse the order of nuget authenticate task and nuget tool installer task, first run nuget tool installer task and then run nuget authenticate task.

Comment: Does adding the private feed to `packageSources` and setting `packageSourceCredentials` also doesn't work? Normally this should work.

Comment: It worked for Nuget 4.6.2 or below but not for 5.8.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you end up solving this?

Comment: No I did not - I ended up sticking with 4.6.2 for now.

Comment: Any solutions for this yet? I have the same issue

Comment: Thank you my friend you save my life @HughLin

Answer (score 0):

Adding your credentials to the `Nuget.Config` should work, the only difference is that the format for the `Nuget.Config` file has slightly changed for the newer versions of nuget, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)
to see how to correctly format your nuget.config file.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a PAT for your user@email.de
- I recommend to add a variable group: **feedCredentials** (e.G. variables PAT as secret variable and variable USER_VARIABLE) in azure devops/organisation/project/Pipelines/Library
- link this to your variables in your build.yml:

  ```
   variables:
   - group: feedCredentials
  ```
- map this to the tasks where needed

  ```
   - task: NuGetCommand@2
   displayName: 'NuGet restore **/your.sln'
   env:
     USER_VARIABLE : $(USER_VARIABLE) 
     PAT : $(PAT)
   inputs:
     restoreSolution: '**/your.sln'
     feedsToUse: 'config'
     nugetConfigPath: 'Nuget.config'
  ```
- don't miss the mapping in your nuget.config in your git repo in the root directory, or the specified nugetConfigPath. Like @Hugh_Lin wrote
- Try your Build

Answer (score -4):

You can also use the Windows Credential Manager, which is a **significantly** more secure way to store your credentials.

[image]

### More Sources

- [Reset NuGet credentials in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891117/reset-nuget-credentials-in-vs2017)
- [Nuget Package Source is not prompting for credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798957/nuget-package-source-is-not-prompting-for-credentials)
- [Why is Visual Studio 2022 no longer prompting me for credentials during NuGet package restore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75477450/why-is-visual-studio-2022-no-longer-prompting-me-for-credentials-during-nuget-pa)

You can even add credentials via powershell if it's a build machine

- [How to add Windows Credentials via Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75193098/how-to-add-windows-credentials-via-powershell)

Comment: That doesn't seem germane to trying to get credentials configured for an azure devops pipeline.

Comment: @Austin_G If you add the domain and your username/password to the windows credential manager, it'll just work, and your username/password will be secure. That's what I do. Explain how that's not relevant?

Comment: @KellyElton is your answer specific to private build agents?

Comment: @Rock No, it would work for either.

Comment: @KellyElton So you are claiming that setting a Windows Credential, which is stored on your local machine, will somehow be magically transported to the Microsoft hosted build servers?

Comment: @jklemmack It's not magic, it's pretty basic Windows behavior, give it a shot. Nuget will use the Windows Credential Manager if you have credentials saved in there.
I'm surprised this would be so controversial, nobody really knows about this? It's been around since Windows XP...

Comment: @KellyElton I think you're missing the point that a build agent can be set up on a completely different machine.  A (developer machine local) secure Windows credential is NOT saved into the YAML of a build pipeline.  Thus the accepted approach of tokenizing the creds so the pipeline will (securely) use them.  Your approach is perfectly valid and a good practice ... if your build & deploy pipelines are on that specific machine.  But the OP is about Azure though, so off not an appropriate response.

Comment: @jklemmack I understand, though as I pointed out you can add a credential using powershell. So you can have a build step that runs the powershell command. I'm sure there are other ways as well. This way you don't have credentials in plain text whatever machine it's building on. Point being it's a perfectly valid way to solve the problem.