# How to add Windows Credentials via Powershell?

Tags: git, powershell, github, credentials

I am trying to add Windows Credentials for my Github account via powershell.

I type in the below command into powershell:

`cmdkey /add:"git:https://github.com" /user:"myusername" /pass:"myauthtoken"`

It returns error `CMDKEY: The parameter is incorrect.`

How can I fix this?

Note that the above parameter values work when I add credentials via gui with Control Panel -> Credential Manager -> Add a Generic Credential.

Comment: Since it's not a Windows credential, but a "generic credential" in Windows terminology: Try `cmdkey /generic:LegacyGeneric:target=git:https://github.com /user:"myusername" /pass:"myauthtoken"`

Comment: that is correct. accepted your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output of `cmdkey /?`:

> ```
> To create generic credentials:
>    The /add switch may be replaced by /generic to create generic credentials
> ```

If I take a look at the generic github credentials in my vault, their target name is listed as:

```
Target: LegacyGeneric:target=git:https://github.com
```

So, I'd suggest trying the following:

```
cmdkey /generic:LegacyGeneric:target=git:https://github.com /user:"myusername" /pass:"myauthtoken"
```