# How to install a nuget package manualy (without using nuget) in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

The nuget package manager stoped working in visual studio with the following error:

`[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. An error occurred while sending the request. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

I tried all trick avalaible on the internet without success (delete the .nuget folder, adding registry keys, changing proxy setting...), then I think the only thing that will work is reinstalling windows (I'm on Windows 10) but I really don't want to do that right now.
I also tried to download nuget.exe and install a package from the command line with the same result.

So, is there another solution, I know a .nuget file is a zip, but I don't know if I can just extract it in my solution folder or if there's some other things to do ?
Can I use an offline source or another tool to install a package in my solution ?

Comment: yes you can, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for the situation you are experiencing now.

But for using the library, there are also many ways.

## 1, If the package your are using is open source

Then you can refer to this answer to use the package:

[How to install this NuGet package if I don't see it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462220/how-to-install-this-nuget-package-if-i-dont-see-it/75469556#75469556)

The above method is tell you how to use local Nuget Source(In this situation, you don't need nuget credential any more.)

## 2, If the package is not open source

I use Newtonsoft.Json package as the example.

### 1' download the package using nuget command

`nuget install Newtonsoft.Json`

This command will search from all of the nuget sources and caches to download the nuget package.

After the above command, you have two ways:

##### 1'' Go to the root folder of the installed directory, you will find the package there:

[image]

Just configure the root directory as the source in VS package management tool. This step already showed in the "If the package your are using is open source" part on above.

##### 2'' If the package isn't complexible. run the above nuget command in the root directory of your project, then configure the .dll file to your project like this:

[image]

***xxx.csproj***

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="ExampleLibrary" HintPath="Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.2/lib/NugetPackage_sourcepackage.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

### 2' download the package using dotnet command

`dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json`

## 3, How to clean the nuget credentials and package cache

[Clean credentials and caches of nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75477450/why-is-visual-studio-2022-no-longer-prompting-me-for-credentials-during-nuget-pa/75507692#75507692)

This can make the nuget as first start.

---

By the way, if you still encounter strange behavior, could you please share the  package you want to install.

Comment: All solutions ends by using nuget, and nuget doesn't work for any package...

Comment: @Entretoize Hi, what is the package you want to install? :)

Comment: The package is Keras.net